# Export laravel data table to CSV

Tags: laravel

I have data in the view like so

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">

                <div id="users-table-wrapper">
                    <table id="users_table" class="table table-hover table-striped">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                               <th>@lang('app.soldto')</th>
                               <th>@lang('app.soldby')</th>
                                <th>@lang('app.network')</th>
                               <th>@lang('app.plan')</th>
                               <th>@lang('app.sales_date')</th>
                           </tr>
                           @if (count($sales))
                           @foreach ($sales as $sale)
                           <tr>
                            <td>{{ $sale->soldto ?: trans('app.n_a') }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $sale->first_name . ' ' . $sale->last_name }}</td>

                            <td>{{ $sale->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $sale->plan }}</td>
                             <td>{{ $sale->salesdate }}</td>

                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        @else
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6"><em>@lang('app.no_records_found')</em></td>
                        </tr>
                        @endif
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {!! $sales->render() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I use pagination to display 10 rows per page. Like below

[image]

I want to download all this data to CSV. Without running the db query again.

Comment: You might want to use https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Comment: I checked that. There is no such examples for exporting data in view to csv.

Comment: You have to execute the function in your controller, right after fetching the results of your selection. If you want to export the data after a user action, you could consider to save the data in your session storage, and use that data for the export.

Comment: Yes i want to export data after user action but not able to find any tutorial anywhere.

Comment: @DineshhBhardwaj Did you work this out?  I am looking for similar solution.  I need to take into account relationships as well.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up using https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel to export whole months values.

Comment: If you don't want to re-run the query, then you need to use the data that has already been fetched. That data is now located in the browser in the HTML table. You will need a JavaScript solution to turn that into CSV. I've seen solutions like this, but not found any reliable and consistent. Personally, I would rerun the query. Whatever currently submits the query to the server, just invoke that again, but with an additional `export=csv` or similar parameter to tell the server to deliver a CSV file rather than a HTML table. I think that is going to have to be your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Datatable itself provide the buttons to export csv, xls ,pdf etc. Here is the code

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtlp',
    buttons: ['csv','pdf']
} );
```

'#example' is the id of your table

Answer (score -1):

You can use working code below:

```
public static function exportCsv()
{

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    $rows = DB::select( DB::raw("select * from users
                ;") );

    $rows = json_decode(json_encode((array) $rows), true);
    //\Log::info('query'.print_r($rows,true));
     ob_end_clean();

    $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach($rows as $key=>$values)
    {   
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($values as $key=>$value) {
            array_push($arr, $key);
        }
        $line = $arr;
        fputcsv($out, $line);
        break;
    }

    //fputcsv($out, array('Registration', 'Name', 'Checkin Time'));
    foreach($rows as $lines)
    {
        $line = $lines;
        fputcsv($out, $line);
    }
    die;
    fclose($out);
}
```

Comment: My view has drop down options to select various type of data. i do not want to re-run the db query.

Comment: This is just generic code for a solution that does not attempt to answer the question at all.